# Sort by matching value in one column

Tags: mysql

I have a query I'm running that get's me almost what I want....

Here's what I'm getting now when running this:

```
select users.username as spoc, iata.code as site, 
        completed.request as SR, truncate(count(tasks.task) *100/24/1,2) as percentage 
from completed 
join users on users.id = completed.name 
join tasks on tasks.id = completed.task 
join iata on iata.id = completed.code 
group by iata.code 
order by users.username;

+-------------------+----------------+
| spoc    | site | SR   | percentage |
+-------------------+------+------+--+
| carmen  | PVD  | 1110 |      58.33 |
| everton | BUD  | 1114 |      120.83 |
| everton | BUS  | 1112 |      110.33 |
| everton | BUS  | 1112 |      110.33 |
| everton | BUS  | 1113 |      110.33 |
| everton | BUS  | 1112 |      110.33 |
| everton | BUS  | 1112 |      110.33 |
| everton | BUD  | 1114 |      120.83 |
| everton | BUD  | 1115 |      120.83 |
| everton | BUD  | 1115 |      45.83 |
```

The reason some of these values are hitting over 100% is because they repeat tasks under a different SR and it's calculating them all in the COUNT.

What I'm looking for in the query is to COUNT task by unique SR....this way they should never surpass 100%. I hope that makes sense.

Comment: What is `24`? You have it as part of your percentage calculation.

Comment: `count(distinct tasks.task)`

Answer (score 0):

You shoul use group by for all the column not in aggregation function

```
 select users.username as spoc, iata.code as site, 
    completed.request as SR, truncate(count(tasks.task) *100/24/1,2) as percentage 
from completed 
join users on users.id = completed.name 
join tasks on tasks.id = completed.task 
join iata on iata.id = completed.code 
group by  users.username, iata.code, completed.request
order by users.username;
```

Comment: The 24 is the number of tasks...I divide by that to get the percentage.

Comment: Thanks scaisedge, I'll try that.